# Ionic facebook login automatically with ngCordova.plugins.oauth

Tags: oauth, ionic-framework, ngcordova

I'm using `Ionic` framework and `ngCordova.plugins.oauth` plugin.
Is there a way to login to facebook with `$cordovaOauth` automatically without asking for user and password when the facebook app is installed on the device?

If not, is there other way to do it on Ionic?

Comment: Facebook app is encrypt the username & password. So it's not possible to get userName and password. And facebook didnt allow you do that. You have use inapp browser.

Comment: @cfprabhu Ok. but some apps use inapp browser and skips the login part if you are already login to facebook. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are but not from $cordovaOauth. Here is the plugin https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin.
You have to follow the instruction there to install (I am using this in ionic project and is working great).